# Enviar contraseña por email mediante php

Tags: php, mysql, email

Necesito obtener la contraseña de una **BD** y enviarla por **email**, el correo electrónico sera ingresado en un formulario. lo que tengo hasta el momento obtengo la contraseña pero ahora necesito comprobar si el email ingresado es igual a la de la BD y enviarlo ...

¿ Alguna idea para continuar ?

**Codigo PHP**

```
  <?php
require('conexion.php');



$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario']);

$sql="select * from Administrador WHERE email_Admin = '$usuario'"; 
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    $error = '';
    $rows = $result->num_rows;

if($rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['email_Admin'] = $row['email_Admin'];



}
else {

            $error = "El email ingresado no existe en nuestros registros.";
        }






?>
<html>
    <head>
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="insignia.ico">
        <title>Recuperar contraseña</title>
               <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css">
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                          <center>
                          <img src="santo_tomas.jpg" width="185" height="248">



        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" > 

                        <div id="h1">Recuperar contraseña</div>
                         <section>
            <div><input class="form-element form-field" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Email" type="text" ></div>

                          </section>



                          <section>
            <div><input class="form-element form-button" name="login" type="submit" value="Enviar" id="button"></div> 
                           </section>
        </form> 
        <div style = "font-size:16px; color:#00695C;"><?php echo isset($error) ? utf8_decode($error) : '' ; ?></div>



</center>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para enviar un correo electrónico mediante `PHP` se podría utilizar varios métodos, podrías utilizar la función `mail()` la que te han mencionado, o también existen una librería llamado `PHPMailer` muy popular y fácil de implementar.

También veo un poco vulnerable tu código, antes de realizar nuestra consulta `SQL` podríamos hacer algunas comprobaciones mediante `PHP`, por ejemplo, si está definido nuestro formulario y no es `NULL`, o si el input no este vacío, etc.

Descargar Librería [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

**Ejemplo mediante PHPMailer:**

```
<?php
 //Reseteo variables.
 $error = $usuario = NULL;

 //Comprobamos si esta definida el formulario y no es NULL.
 if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    //Comprobamos que no este vacio nuestro input.
    if (empty($_POST['usuario'])) {
        $error = 'El email es obligatorio';
    } else {
        //Importante, añadir la conexion donde se va utilizar.
        require_once'conexion.php';
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario']);
    }

    //Si es verdadero nuestro input, continuamos.
    if ($usuario) {         
        //Sentencia
        $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Administrador WHERE email_Admin = '$usuario' LIMIT 1"); 
        //Comprobamos si existe el registro.
        if ($sql->num_rows===1) {
            $row = $sql->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['email_Admin'] = $row['email_Admin'];

            //Compones nuestro correo electronico

            //Incluimos libreria PHPmailer (deberas descargarlo).
            require'class.phpmailer.php';

            //Nuevo correo electronico.
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            //Caracteres.
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

            //De dirección correo electrónico y el nombre
            $mail->From = "info@tudominio.com";
            $mail->FromName = "Nombre de dominio";

            //Dirección de envio y nombre.
            $mail->addAddress($row['email_Admin'], 'Nombre Admin');
            //Dirección a la que responderá destinatario.
            $mail->addReplyTo("info@tudominio.com","Tunombre");

            //BCC ->  incluir copia oculta de email enviado.
            $mail->addBCC("copia@tudominio.com");

            //Enviar codigo HTML o texto plano.
            $mail->isHTML(true);

            //Titulo email.
            $mail->Subject = "Nuestro titulo";
            //Cuerpo email con HTML.
            $mail->Body = "Tu contraseña actualizada es:" . $row['tu_contrasena']; //Podrias personalizar mediante HTML y CSS :)

            //Comprobamos el envio.
            if(!$mail->send()) {                    
                $error = "Ocurrió un error inesperado con él envió del correo electrónico, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde, disculpa las molestias.";
            } else {
                $error = "Se envio correctamente el correo electrónico.";
            }   
        } else { //0 registros.
            $error = 'El email ingresado no existe en nuestros registros.';
        } $sql->close();
    }       
 }
?>
```

Te aconsejo a utilizar [sentencias preparadas](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), son muy últiles frente a Inyecciones SQL.

Comment: gracias por los consejos y la Liberia !

Comment: @AshleyBeeb de nada, suerte con tu proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    //Lo obtiene del formulario.
    $email = $_POST['usuario'];
    //Suponiendo que esta la base de datos.
    $sql="select * from Administrador WHERE email_Admin = '$email'"; //Va obtener los datos y si no tiene nada pues no hace nada el programa.
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    $error = '';
    $rows = $result->num_rows;
    if($rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['email_Admin'] = $row['email_Admin'];
        $msg = "Tu contraseña es: ".$row['contraseña'];
        mail($row['email_Admin'], "Mi titulo", $msg);
   }

?>
```

Comment: Eso lo se, pero como dije en la pregunta necesito saber COMO comparar la varible email de formulario con la de bd y despues enviar el correo

Comment: El query lo hace solo

Comment: Dice solo dame los datos que sean de igual direccion de correo.

Comment: la variblae $email contiene el correo de la base de datos, ahora necesito compararlo con lo ingresado en el formulario y si son iguales enviar la contraseña al correo ingresado

Comment: La sentencia `WHERE` hace eso SOLO DAME EL QUE SEA IGUAL.

Comment: he actualizado la pregunta, ahora necesito solo enviar el correo

Comment: Ahi lo he actualizado para el envio del correo.

Comment: gracias ah funcionado, pero se puede personalizar quien lo envía y el titulo ?

Comment: Obvio cambia los string simplemente

Comment: entiendo gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar si el email del formulario es igual al de la BBDD, captura el email con $_POST, o el metodo del formulario, Luego ese mismo valor que capturaste del formulario manda la llamada a la base de datos con SELECT, si te devuelve el resultado evalua con un condicional if, si son iguales procede a terminar la operación, si son diferentes pues avisale al usuario que no es correcto

Comment: Pero el `WHERE` ya le esta haciendo la comprobacion desde la base de datos, el `if` seria si contiene datos (1 = envia, 0 = no envia)

Answer (score -2):

Es el enlace que te dejo, está lo que buscas: [Youtube: 21. Sistema de Usuarios en PHP y MySQL Parte 3: Recuperar Contraseña](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oghl1SjVbbs&t=175s)

Comment: se espera que las respuetas sean de calidad, mostrando un ejemplo mínimo y viable para que el OP sepa como adaptarlo, colocar simplemente enlaces es riesgoso, que pasa si la página deja de funcionar o cierra esa publicación?

Comment: Incluye más información en tu respuesta que un simple enlace a YouTube. Te invito a que veas este artículo acerca de [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Tu respuesta puede mejorar.